# MySQL SELECT COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, unique, distinct

I am getting from the below query

```
SELECT co.mobility_theme, COUNT(DISTINCT ca.user_id) AS n 
FROM courses_apply AS ca LEFT JOIN dy41s_courses AS co ON ca.course_id = co.id 
WHERE ca.submission IS NULL AND ca.`call` LIKE  '1b' 
GROUP BY co.mobility_theme 
ORDER BY co.mobility_theme ASC
```

The below result total (133)

```
mobility_theme n

1 =>70

4 =>18

5 =>45
```

What I want to do is: for each mobility theme (1,2 and 5), I have repeated users, so the total unique user_id should be (130), I cannot manage to get unique user_id group by (mobility theme), any help?

Comment: not to the point but what is up with your like clause ?

Comment: It is only to get the records of specify "call"

Comment: i know but it is not a 'like'

Comment: what am i misunderstanding about your problem, i have a repeat user, i get the expected results.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11466/1

Comment: maybe you mean a given user, across say 2 courses ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29cff/1/0 you can see user (1) applied in (1 and 2) and the result counted him in mobility (1,2) I need to count him in one of them only

Comment: gottcha but user1 is technically in 2 themes so how would you want the results to look !

Comment: I want to count each user once among all records and then divide the unique users across the mobility theme

Comment: so cut him in half or thirds. go with the min() of course id? like i said how would you desire to have your sqlfiddle results look. cant move on from there

Comment: When user is applying to multiple mobility levels it will be counted in each on so the final total result is fake, what I need to do is if is counted once in one of the mobility levels don't count it in the other? is it can be done in one mysql query or i have to code it? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29cff/1/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to arbitrarily choose one of the mobility themes.  This method chooses the one with the minimum value:

```
select mobility_theme, COUNT(*) as Numusers
from (select ca.user_id, MIN(co.mobility_theme) as mobility_theme
      from courses_apply ca LEFT JOIN
           dy41s_courses co
           ON ca.course_id = co.id 
      WHERE ca.submission IS NULL AND ca.`call` LIKE  '1b' 
      group by ca.user_id
     ) caco
group by mobility_theme
```